# Job shop scheduling with events that should be completed simultaneously

Tags: algorithms, optimization, scheduling, combinatory-logic

I'm working on a scheduling algorithm that schedules a set of events with an event duration to a set of agents with various working times.

However, some events require more than one agent to be assigned to them to be completed. The event must be completed by both agents simultaneously.

Does anybody know of an algorithm that can solve this problem?
Does anybody also know whether this problem has a name? E.g. is it an extension of the job shop scheduling problem (for instance)?

Comment: See if this paper gives you clues in the right direction: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260003471_Group_Activity_Selection_Problem